# Send email in oracle 10g

Tags: jsp, jdbc

Hi I have 2 tables and their outputs are as below

```
table1:
userID Email address
Rakesh rakesh.k@xyz.com
hari   hari.m@xyz.com
abc    abc@xyz.com


table2:

subject1
subject2
subject3
```

i want a query to send an email from abc(i login into my website as abc) to Rakesh or hari(based on my selection from a jsp) with subject as any one from table 2 and it should be appended with string "reallocated"

please help me tanks

Comment: You want to send emails from database or from JSP?

Comment: i want to send an email from jsp where the addresses are taken from database

Comment: You can use Javamail API's to send emails from JSP. It would be better to use a Java class for sending emails and use that class from JS, that way you could re-use this class for sending emails from your application. Or call the database procedure for sending emails and call it from JSP/Java. having send email code in JSP is not a good at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending emails from database you need to have a procedure using `UTIL_SMTP` or some other email protocols. For `UTIL_SMTP` create a procedure as follows

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE send_mail (P_SENDER in varchar2,
                     P_RECIPIENT in varchar2,
                     P_CC in varchar2,
                     P_SUBJECT   in varchar2,
                     P_MESSAGE   in varchar2) is

mailhost varchar2(30) := 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx';
mail_conn utl_smtp.connection;
crlf varchar2(2) := CHR(13)||CHR(10);
mesg varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(mailhost,25);
  mesg := 'Date: '||to_char(sysdate,'dd Mon yy hh24:mi:ss' )||crlf||
          'FROM: '||P_SENDER||'>'||crlf||'Subject: '||P_SUBJECT||crlf||
          'To: '||P_RECIPIENT||crlf||
          'Cc: '||P_CC||crlf||crlf||P_MESSAGE;
  utl_smtp.helo(mail_conn,mailhost);
  utl_smtp.mail(mail_conn,P_SENDER);
  utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_conn,P_RECIPIENT);
  utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_conn,P_CC);
  utl_smtp.data(mail_conn,mesg);
  utl_smtp.quit(mail_conn);
END send_mail;
/
```

You can get `SMTP_HOST` and `SMTP_PORT` from your System Administrator. SMTP_PORT will be 25 by default. Once you have that you could execute your procedure as

```
exec send_mail('abc@xyz.com',
            'rakesh.k@xyz.com',
            'hari.k@xyz.com',
            '<Your subject>',
            '<Your message>');
```

If you want to invoke your procedure for sending emails from JSP, you could call the procedure and pass the parameters from JSP to your procedure. If you want use a select statement for sending emails wrap your procedure in a function and execute function as

```
select <yourfunction(params)> from dual
```

Comment: We don't have to wrangle SMTP. Oracle has provided a better email API, `UTL_MAIL`, since Oracle 10g. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm#i1001668).